# How to use Javascript to delete text box by contents using itemByName in InDesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have an InDesign document containing data, graphs, and tables. I have text boxes that I have named "Values" that either contain data or "n/a". I would like to delete all named text boxes that do not contain the string "n/a". The following script is working to delete all text boxes that do not contain n/a, but it deletes all text boxes, including those that are not named. I've tried using doc.textFrames.itemByName("Values"), but it does not work with texts.length.

Any suggestions? Or resources that I could look at?

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var find = "n/a";
var texts = doc.textFrames;
var i = count;
var count = texts.length;

for (i = count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (texts[i].contents.match(find) != find) {
        texts[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some related HTML for this and make a somewhat working demo? As close as you can get it.  Also, why does this have an `adobe-indesign` tag on the question?

Comment: Because it is for an InDesign document. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: ok, interesting. I wasn't aware that had scripting with it!

Comment: Yup. You can do some pretty cool stuff with it. It is frustrating sometimes though haha.

Comment: Is `itemByName` a built in inDesign method?  If this were plain HTML/JS if you had `<textarea name="foo">` elements you could use `document.querySelectorAll('textarea[name="foo"]')` to select them all.

Comment: Yes, it's a built in method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the line:

```
if (texts[i].contents.match(find) != find) {
```

with:

```
if (texts[i].name == "Values" && texts[i].contents.match(find) != find) {
```

---

More native and more efficient approach would be:

```
var frames = app.activeDocument.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();

while (f = frames.pop())
    if (f.name == "Values" && f.contents != "n/a") f.remove();
```

To iterate through `collection.everyItem().getElements()` is usually much faster than through a `collection`.

Comment: Wow Yuri, as always, fantastic work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! The second code that you sent does seem to speed it up a little bit. Much cleaner than my scrapped together original code.